# Having problems with a join query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table called dogs with the following rows

*dog_id (primary)*

*dog_name*

*sire*

*dam*

For sire or dam of a dog I enter a dog_id relating to a dogs name.
I am trying to list a dogs sire and dam through the dog_id row.
However when I run the query it does not show dog_name in sire just the dog_id.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT dogs.dog_id, dogs.dog_name, pedigree.sire, pedigree.dam 
          FROM dogs 
          JOIN dogs pedigree";
$get_pedigree = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($row_dog = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_pedigree))
$sire   = $row['sire'];
$dam   = $row['dam']; 
?>
```

Comment: Also the pedigree part is not another table everything is in one table. I watched a video that suggested to use an alias so I used pedigree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `ON` clause in order for SQL to know how the tables are linked;

For example

```
SELECT dogs.dog_id, dogs.dog_name, pedigree.sire, pedigree.dam 
FROM dogs 
JOIN pedigree ON pedigree.dog_id = dogs.dog_id
```

Also by using a `JOIN` rather than say a `LEFT JOIN` you will only get results if both tables have a matching id.

Updated response;

If sire and dam are self-referencing ids you should be able to do;

```
SELECT dogs.dog_id, 
       dogs.dog_name, 
       father.dog_id AS father_dog_id, 
       father.dog_name AS father_dog_name, 
       mother.dog_id AS mother_dog_id, 
       mother.dog_name AS mother_dog_name 
FROM dogs 
LEFT JOIN dogs AS father ON father.dog_id = dogs.sire
LEFT JOIN dogs AS mother ON mother.dog_id = dogs.dam
```

Comment: only one table the pedigree was a alias I used. Its a self join

Comment: Provide details of your schema and what you expect the desired result to be.

Comment: For this join one table to join itself.
Rows are:
dog_id (Primary)
dog_name
sire
dam

The sire and the dam are dogs listed in dog_name and have a dog_id.
When I do a query to list the sire and dam it show dog_id not a dog_name

Comment: Are the sire and dam columns the id of the father and mother or just their names?

Comment: Please see my updated response to see if that works for your scenario.

Comment: the sire and dam are the dogs id from dog_id, the problem is when sire and dam result show it gives me the dog_id which is correct but I want it to display the dog_name

Comment: You should be able to pull that using $row[‘father_dog_name’]. Please note that my quote marks are being converted to smart quotes to best not to copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off and you need an `on` clause so it knows how the two tables are related.

```
SELECT dogs.dog_id, dogs.dog_name, pedigree.sire, pedigree.dam 
FROM dogs
JOIN pedigree
on dogs.dog_id = pedigree.dog_id
```

I assume `pedigree` has a dog_id as well?

An alternative to `on` can be `using` if both tables use the same column name:

```
using(dog_id)
```

Okay, with the updated description you can do something like this to get the father and mothers name.

```
select group_concat(parents.name), dog.id, dog.name 
from dogs as dog
left join dogs as parents
on dog.mom = parents.id or dog.dad= parents.id
group by dog.id
```

or you can do the double join above if you need both columns independent.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c548/5

Comment: only one table the pedigree is a alias i watched a video that said to use it?

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to do a self join? Maybe I don't know enough about dogs, what's the sire vs. dam? Maybe you're looking for `coalesce`?

Comment: sire is the father and dam is the mother